# Reversing the row ordering in Androids GridLayout

Tags: java, android

I'm working with a GridLayout that I'm populating programatically. the children in the layout populate as so:

0 1 2

3 4 5

6 7 8

I would like it to populate like:

6 7 8

3 4 5

0 1 2

Is there a simple way to do this?

this is my code:

```
GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

    layout.setColumnCount(Chess.NUM_OF_COLS);
    layout.setRowCount(Chess.NUM_OF_ROWS);
    GridLayout.spec(0, 63);

    for(int x = 0; x < Chess.NUM_OF_COLS ; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < Chess.NUM_OF_ROWS; y++){
            int finalX = x;
            int finalY = y;
            ImageView squareImageView = new ImageView(getContext());
            squareImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.square);
            squareImageView.setColorFilter(Chess.isWhiteSquare(Chess.coorToSqi(finalX, finalY)) ?
                    Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.height = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.width = GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(finalX);
            param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(finalY);
            squareImageView.setLayoutParams(param);

            squareImageView.setOnClickListener(onSquareClick(finalX, finalY, layout));
            layout.addView(squareImageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my opinion you would have to do it manually.. but you could write a method that swap whole row which another row, so after populate, you could just swap first row whit last row.. but it is just idea, never done this.. Another idea, its some chess game? So i guess you have white and black figures and you want once white on the top and once on the bottom? If so, there is simpler way to do that.. just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is independent of a UI component, so let's focus on how you would populate a 2x2 matrix instead.

We need to populate from max to min, and the column number needs to start from the highest column number instead of 0.

e.g.

```
matrix[0][2]
matrix[0][1]
matrix[0][0]
matrix[1][2]
```

...and so on

The following is an algorithm to do that:

```
   public void test(){
        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;
        int[][] rowsColumns = new int[rows][cols];
        int max = rows * cols - 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            for(int j = rows-1; j >= 0; j--){
                rowsColumns[i][j] = max--;
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            System.out.print(rowsColumns[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    }
```

Notice we start with the highest potential value, since they're sequential, and just decrement that for each iteration of the inner loop. That gives us the following output:

```
678
345
012
```